# Using VB is there a better way to remove the last X amount of items from the ListBox?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listbox

To remove last 10 items I use

```
For i As Integer = 1 To 10
    ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(ListBox1.Items.Count - 1)
Next i
```

Is there a better, one line solution?

EDIT:

I see that my question is put on hold and would like to explain a little better what I was asking. In my stride to follow the rules of this board I tried to make the question short and to the point and perhaps that made it not clear. Please keep in mind that I am very new to VB, just a couple of weeks into it, so there is a lot I don’t know yet.

I have some need-based experience with VBA and Excel and that’s what made me ask the question. Let’s say I have a list of items in Column A of the Excel document and I need to delete last 10 items from the list. For the time being pretend that there are always more than 10 items and we don’t need to account for there being less and also that there are no empty cells within the list. The code I would use would be:

Range("A999999").End(xlUp).Offset(-10, 0).Range("A1:A10").Delete Shift:=xlUp

See how it’s a one line solution without looping through each cell? I just give it a range and told it to delete it. So this made me curious about VB and whether there might be something similar instead of looping through every item.  I thought there could be and I may not be familiar with it due to my inexperience.  Basically my question is - is something simple like ListBox1.Items.RemoveLast(10) exists in VB or not? Hope this helped some of you to understand where I was coming from with my question and thanks for reading.

Comment: It is only better when it is correct and *you* know how to write it and maintain it.  Write correct code first, make it work when the ListBox has 9 or less items.

Comment: Hans Passant could you please elaborate on what you think is wrong with my code? It works for me to remove the last 10 items from a ListBox.  Is it only that it didn’t account for the possibility of a there being less items? If I had to account for that I would use the code below. Does it seem correct to you?

`If ListBox1.Items.Count > 10 Then
For i As Integer = 1 To 10
ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(ListBox1.Items.Count - 1)
Next i
Else
ListBox1.Items.Clear()
End If `

Comment: @HansPassant the idea for the above code is to count the items in the box. If there are more than 10 items than remove the last 10 items. If the count equals to 10 or less, then simply clear the entire ListBox.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in this way:

```
    Dim amountToRemove As Integer = 10
    Dim items As IEnumerable(Of Object) = Me.ListBox1.Items.Cast(Of Object)()

    If (items.Count < amountToRemove) Then
        Throw New IndexOutOfRangeException(message:="...")

    Else
        Me.ListBox1.SuspendLayout()
        For i As Integer = 0 To (amountToRemove - 1)
            Me.ListBox1.Items.Remove(items.Last)
        Next i
        Me.ListBox1.ResumeLayout()

    End If
```

If you want a single-line solution, put the logic into a method, then use one line to call it.